# codeigniter redirect occuring on local environment but not production site

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Ion_auth with codeigniter. I have the following:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data))
    {
        //check to see if we are creating the user
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'PLEASE CHECK EMAIL');
        redirect("auth", 'refresh');
```

This works fine with expected redirection to the 'auth' controller in my wamp development environment. But  I just get a blank screen on the remote website.

Any ideas on what to do next?

addendum:

I've changed the error reporting to the highest level on the production site and am now getting:

Severity: Warning

```
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mydomain.com/application/config/production/database.php:1)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 675
```

Severity: Warning

```
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at mydomain.com/application/config/production/database.php:1)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 540
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Chrome's developer tools? If you are in Chrome, press F12. Are there any errors on the page? What does the request look like? Maybe put a "die('works find to this point');" at the top of your auth.php controller and see if you even make it there.

Comment: David, I put die('works find to this point'); in the auth index function and the text was printed locally but not online sugesting it does not make it there. Therefore there is a problem with at least 1 of the 2 lines in the if statement above

Comment: Also I don't think its looping if thats what you mean because  auth is a different controller than the basic controller

Comment: How come you don't want to: redirect("auth/login", 'refresh'); ??? This is how I redirect.

Comment: I'm calling it a day...if you still have no luck, you might have to try manually going to that route (type it manually in the address bar). If manually going to the controller by entering the URL works, then I'm baffled why the statement above doesn't work.

Comment: i vaguely remember facing the exact problem when I was attempting to use ion auth ( i ended up using bit auth). I dont remember the exact solution, but you may want to look into your base_url, and your php versions in both servers.

Comment: redirect("/auth", 'refresh'); Put a slash in the front of the auth and try it once,,,

Comment: I tried redirect("auth/login", 'refresh'); and redirect("/auth", 'refresh'); . Still not working

Comment: Please check out my addendum. Will this help?

Comment: Check the response in chrome developer. It might be the case server sends some empty header string before the redirect and that is why it is not working. In that case need to make sure none of the files has something before <?php tag and after ?> tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mydomain.com/application/config/production/database.php:1)

This is usually caused by whitespace being output by a file that is included before a session is started.

Make sure there's no extraneous whitespace (including new lines, spaces, etc.) in your `application/config/production/database.php` file. The very first characters in that file should be `<?php` and you should omit the closing `?>` tag entirely to ensure you don't get a problem with, say, `?>\n`...

Comment: There was a single whitespace character at the beginning of the file. Its now working.